# Cleaning all memory leaks in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have tried a lot to stop all leaks from my app. But when I am syncing large amount of data from 
server then my ios application leaking memory.

Now I want to clean all leaked memory after some time of interval or you can say whenever i get call in function.

```
-(void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    UIAlertView* alertobj = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Info" message:@"This Application facing memory issue." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alertobj show];

    NSLog(@"memory issue occur");
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

Is there any way??

Answer (score 0):

Nope, you can't do that.

I ran into a similar issue, sync data in smaller chunks and read about `@autoreleasepool`

Basically I sync between 500~1500 objects at a time depending on how much data is in the objects, wrapping them in the `@autoreleasepool` keeps memory low by getting rid of those objects as soon as I am done with them.